# How to investigate slow Heroku application

Tags: reactjs, django, performance, heroku

I deployed my first two applications on a free Heroku account, but the performance is terribly slow. Is it with my code? Do I need to upgrade my Heroku subscription? How do I investigate what's wrong?

1st App: Django Rest API for backend

2nd App: React for frontend

Comment: First, try to identify the bottleneck in your system. To find the bottleneck, you should set up the logging, use application monitoring tools.
Once, you are able to find the bottleneck then you will get an idea about what to do next.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are not talking about the fact that the server goes to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity and takes about 30s to go back up ?

Comment: React has no business being slow anywhere on any server unless your code is inefficient. Are you serving a production build as static files, or are you using a development server like `react-scripts start`?

Comment: I suggest you peek at your [metrics](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/metrics).